# Adding all external libraries stored from a directory into Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, wildcard, qmake

Is there a way to add all libraries from a given folder without adding every single one to the `LIBS` variable in Qt project file.

I've put all libraries (DLLs (win) or SOs (unix)) in one directory (MYLIBS) along with header files and tried something like this:

```
LIBS *= -L$$PWD/MYLIBS -l*
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/MYLIBS
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/MYLIBS
```

It didn't work with error message `cannot find -l*`. 
Is it possible for `qmake` to use the wildcards while creating Makefiles?

Comment: I do not think that this is possible. As an alternative you could use a short batch script to write all filenames into a text file and copy this into the Qt pro file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [files](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#files-pattern-recursive-false), [basename](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#basename-variablename) and [replace](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#replace-string-old-string-new-string) functions to get what you need:

```
LIBS *= -L$$PWD/MYLIBS
win32 {
    SHARED_LIB_FILES = $$files($$PWD/MYLIBS/*.dll)
    for(FILE, SHARED_LIB_FILES) {
        BASENAME = $$basename(FILE)
        LIBS += -l$$replace(BASENAME,.dll,)
    }
}
unix {
    SHARED_LIB_FILES = $$files($$PWD/MYLIBS/*.so)
    for(FILE, SHARED_LIB_FILES) {
        BASENAME = $$basename(FILE)
        LIBS += -l$$replace(BASENAME,.so,)
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside the for loop, we should change the 
``LIBS += -l$$replace(BASENAME,.dll,)``
to
``LIBS += -l$$replace(BASENAME,\.dll,)``
because the . is a literal char instead of the . in regular expression.